# Will an Asus Transformer Pad Infinity work in the UK if I ship it over from USA

Tags: compatibility, localization

I want to ship my Asus Transformer Pad Infinity from the USA to the UK as it's cheaper. Will I run into any compatibility issues? (It does not have 3G.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Will android tablets from US work in the UK?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15382/will-android-tablets-from-us-work-in-the-uk)

Comment: See also [Will an Asus Transformer Prime bought in the U.S. work in Portugal?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/25935/will-an-asus-transformer-prime-bought-in-the-u-s-work-in-portugal)

Answer (score 1):

The Transformer Pad Infinity itself would function fine in the UK. You would probably have an issue with the US charger and would need to get an adapter or charge via USB. As far as I can tell GPS and WiFi should work the same no matter where in the world you are.

Answer (score 0):

I have the original Transformer Eee Pad (great device highly recommend any version of Transformer tablets). I actually took it to Europe this summer (I live in the US) and it worked fine EXCEPT for a couple of things:

-As ZnewmaN said, you will have to get a converter for the charger (if you plan to plug it into any sort of outlet).

-I believe the Google Play store MAY be slightly different. I know in France it was (content such as music and books were unavailable when I tried to access Google Play from my tablet in France (I didn't try it in the UK). It is very possible that this is not the case in the UK but you should be aware of it.

Yes, GPS and WiFi work just as well. I tried both in England with out a hitch. Hope this helps clear things up.